# Issues indexing data into elasticsearch in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I am trying to index a whole table of about 47k records into elastic search.  This is not a lot of data.  Regardless, I am chunking the records with eloquent and no matter the size of the chunk, by the 5th "update_mapping" of ES console output, everything just stops.

I'm not 100% sure what information you will need to help debug this, so I will try to cover everything.

Laravel 5.2 hosted inside a vagrant machine, running the Scotch-Vagrant image.

I am using the official docker image from elastic search:

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -e "http.host=0.0.0.0" -e "transport.host=127.0.0.1" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.2.1
```

To work with ES, I am using their official package.  In my composer.json:

```
"elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "^5.1"
```

I used this tutorial to get up and running:
https://michaelstivala.com/learning-elasticsearch-with-laravel/

(Including the "beefed up" wrapper.)

I added a method to his class, as a debugging effor:

```
public function createIndex($params) {
    return $this->client->indices()->create($params);
}
```

I'll get to the createIndex method shortly.

I had to modify his Provider register method to include the host information:

```
public function register()
{

    $hosts = [
        [
            'host' => '10.0.2.2', // the host ip from inside vagrant
            'port' => '9200',
            'scheme' => 'http',
            'user' => 'elastic', // yeah I know, change this.
            'pass' => 'changeme' // I will.
        ]
    ];


    $this->app->bind(Elastic::class, function ($app) use ($hosts) {
        return new Elastic(
            ClientBuilder::create()
                ->setHosts($hosts)
                ->build()
        );
    });
}
```

With this, I have Elasticsearch up and running with my laravel project.  On to the indexing.

```
$elastic = app(Elastic::class);

// Table Causes has 84 records.
Causes::chunk(100, function ($causes) use ($elastic) {
    foreach ($causes as $cause) {
        $elastic->index([
            'index' => 'pwi',
            'type' => 'cause',
            'id' => $cause->cause_id,
            'body' => $cause->toArray()
        ]);
    }
});

// Table Country has 248 records.
Country::chunk(100, function ($countries) use ($elastic) {
    foreach ($countries as $country) {
        $elastic->index([
            'index' => 'pwi',
            'type' => 'country',
            'id' => $country->country_id,
            'body' => $country->toArray()
        ]);
    }
});
```

These index without issue.  Now the big one.

```
// Table Organizations has 47066 records.
Organizations::chunk(5000, function ($organizations) use ($elastic) {
    foreach ($organizations as $organization) {
        $elastic->index([
            'index' => 'pwi',
            'type' => 'organization',
            'id' => $organization->org_id,
            'body' => $organization->toArray()
        ]);
    }
});
```

When I run all three indexes with the above configuration, this is the output I get in the docker console window

```
 [2017-03-28T19:22:11,305][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [knre-px] [pwi] creating index, cause [auto(index api)], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
 [2017-03-28T19:22:11,443][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [knre-px] [pwi/Jswi4XuJTyqj56edsNfjfg] create_mapping [cause]
 [2017-03-28T19:22:16,190][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [knre-px] [pwi/Jswi4XuJTyqj56edsNfjfg] create_mapping [country]
 [2017-03-28T19:22:16,604][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [knre-px] [pwi/Jswi4XuJTyqj56edsNfjfg] update_mapping [country]
 [2017-03-28T19:22:29,088][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [knre-px] [pwi/Jswi4XuJTyqj56edsNfjfg] create_mapping [organization]
 [2017-03-28T19:22:29,375][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [knre-px] [pwi/Jswi4XuJTyqj56edsNfjfg] update_mapping [organization]
 [2017-03-28T19:22:29,453][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [knre-px] [pwi/Jswi4XuJTyqj56edsNfjfg] update_mapping [organization]
 [2017-03-28T19:22:30,309][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [knre-px] [pwi/Jswi4XuJTyqj56edsNfjfg] update_mapping [organization]
 [2017-03-28T19:22:30,717][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [knre-px] [pwi/Jswi4XuJTyqj56edsNfjfg] update_mapping [organization]
 [2017-03-28T19:22:33,247][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [knre-px] [pwi/Jswi4XuJTyqj56edsNfjfg] update_mapping [organization]
```

For organizations, regardless of the chunk size, it gets to that 5th update mapping, and that is where everything comes to a halt.  Chunks of 10, or chunks of 5000 same result. The browser window is still spinning.  There is never any additional output in the console.  It just sits there, eventually giving me the maximum execution time exceeded error.

I have tried increasing the shard count, using that createIndex method, before I index anything I run:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'pwi',
    'body' => [
        'settings' => [
            'number_of_shards' => 10
        ],
    ]
];

$elastic->createIndex($params);
```

With no changes to the final results.

I was having this error when I started up the docker image:

```
max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
```

Running this:
    sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144

(https://github.com/docker-library/elasticsearch/issues/111)
Fixed that.

It isn't an issue with the data.  It isn't getting stuck on the same record if the chunk size is 10, and on the next try the chunk size is 5000.

I was using the Elasticquent package (Only I had to use ES 2.4), and had the same issue when I got to indexing the organizations table.  Using chunks of 200 got past it though (Not with the current process though).  I need to search across types, and I cannot find a package that will easily do that so I've decided to do it on my own.  If I cancel the index request, and then start using my search code (not indexing anything, just using what has been indexed) everything works great!

If I were a betting man, I'd say there is something wrong with my configuration.  Or the ES/Docker server.  Unfortunately I don't know what to google.  47k in records is NOT a lot... right?  So what am I missing?

Thanks for reading all of this.  I appreciate any assistance.

[edit]

I changed the code:

```
Organizations::chunk(200, function ($organizations) use ($elastic) {
    foreach ($organizations as $organization) {
        $elastic->index([
            'index' => 'pwi',
            'type' => 'organization',
            'id' => $organization->org_id,
            'body' => [
                "org_name" => $organization->org_name,
                "org_desc" => $organization->org_desc,
            ]
        ]);
    }
});
```

And now it it doesn't get past the first create map:

```
[2017-03-28T20:00:14,543][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService] [eBlAEK7] [pwi] creating index, cause [auto(index api)], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2017-03-28T20:00:14,668][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [eBlAEK7] [pwi/Fqj91gS9Q6CBfl4z2ZNvXw] create_mapping [organization]
```

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution was to increase the execution time.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
```

Is vagrant maybe just that slow?  It took 8 minutes to index those 47k of records.

Either way, this was a solution.  I feel not the best?